# Why cmake on opencv branch 3.4 says its 4.8?

Tags: c++, git, opencv, cmake, makefile

I have following directory structure with various opencv related github repos cloned and specific branches checked out as specifid in from of their name in brackets

```
/ws/opencv (branch 4.8)
/ws/opencv_contrib (branch 4.8)
/ws/opencv34 
   └── opencv (branch 3.4)
   └── opencv_contrib (branch 3.4)
```

Please refer output to ascertain branches in appendix below. At the beginning I did `make install` inside folder `/ws/opencv/build`. However, I have now done `make uninstall`.

Now I also want to build opencv 3.4. I tried `cmake ..` inside `/ws/opencv34/opencv/build` directory. This generated bunch of files in build directory. I checked OpenCVConfig.cmake and it had following lines:

```
SET(OpenCV_VERSION 4.8.0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_MAJOR  4)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_MINOR  8)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_PATCH  0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_TWEAK  0)
SET(OpenCV_VERSION_STATUS "-dev")
```

Why cmake is declaring opencv to have version 4.8, even though I have checked out version 3.4?

PS: This is causing `make` for another app to fail, since it requires opencv 3.4, even though I have specified following in its CMakeLists.txt:

```
set(OpenCV_DIR /ws/opencv34/opencv/build)
```

**Appendix - branches**

```
/ws/opencv# git branch
* 4.x

/ws/opencv_contrib# git branch
* 4.x

/ws/opencv34/opencv# git branch
* 3.4
  4.x

/ws/opencv34/opencv_contrib# git branch
* 3.4
  4.x
```

**Update**

I created `ws/opencv34/opencv` and `ws/opencv34/opencv_contrib` by copying `ws/opencv` and `ws/opencv_contrib` and then doing `git checkout 3.4`. Somehow it does not seem to do real checkout even though it says `3.4` in the output `git branch`. Now I deleted both `ws/opencv34/opencv` and `ws/opencv34/opencv_contrib` and cloned afresh. It started working as expected! Please let me know why?

Comment: So your updated question is not about specifically CMake and OpenCV, but about general git behavior when cloning/copiing/branching, am I right? Your are better to provide more details about your steps with git.